# Applescript prints "missing value" instead of empty string

Tags: applescript

I'm using this Applescript to display the Reminders from a list called "Cities" on my Desktop using GeekTool, but for some reason for every reminder in this list without anything in the body it prints out "missing value". How can I make it so it doesn't?

```
set theList to {}
set theOutput to ""

tell application "Reminders"
    repeat with i from 1 to (count of every reminder of list "Cities")
        if reminder i of list "Cities" is not completed then
            set theList to theList & {name, body} of reminder i of list "Cities"
        end if
    end repeat
    repeat with i from 1 to (count of every item of theList)
        set theOutput to (theOutput & item i of theList as string) & return
    end repeat
    return theOutput
end tell
```

The output I'm after is:

Istanbul - visited Mar 2008
Las Vegas
Kyoto - visited Feb 2012

Currently its:

Istanbul
visited Mar 2008
Las Vegas
Kyoto
visited Dec 2012

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because the value of an empty body is `missing value`, which, when you convert it to a string, becomes `"missing value"`. To avoid this, you can explicitly check for a missing value in the reminder before adding it to `theList`.

```
repeat with i from 1 to (count of every reminder of list "Cities")
    set theReminder to reminder i of list "Cities"
    if theReminder is not completed then
        if the body of theReminder is not missing value then
            set theList to theList & {name, body} of theReminder
        else
            set theList to theList & {name of theReminder, ""}
        end if
     end if
 end repeat
```

If you don't want a blank line between reminders with no body, you can simply use `{name of theReminder}` in the else clause.

Comment: That works but how would I but the body of the reminder on the same line as the name. Can I just concatenate the strings?

Comment: Sure. Just replace `{name, body} of theReminder` with `(name of theReminder & " - " & body of theReminder)`, then get rid of the empty string in the second one.